# CakePHP Pagination - how do I see the Paginator values from within the Controller?

Tags: cakephp

I am using the CakePHP pagination helper within my controller as such

```
$this->paginate = array(
                    'Entity'    => array(
                            'limit'    => $limit,
                            'order'    => $order
                        )
                );

$entities = $this->paginate('Entity', $conditions);
```

Within my view, I am not using the $paginator variable to display the pagination navigation elements (ie total count, current page, total page...)

My question is:  how do I access the $paginator variable from within the controller?  I'm assuming it is set after the controller calls the $this->paginate method.  I would like to see within the controller the total count of records that the paginate found.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

after calling the `paginate()` method, the results are stored in `$this->params['paging'][YOUR_MODEL_NAME]`

To see them:

```
pr($this->params['paging']);
```

Cheers